# TextBox selection color and selection brackets color

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm styling a TextBox control for Universal App (Windows & Windows Phone). I've found that selection color could be set by 'SelectionHighlightColor' property (blue on the picture). But somehow selection brackets seems to keep system accent color (green in my case):

[image]

How do I set brackets color or redefine accent color?

Update:

I've tried to redefine lots of theme brushes and colors, such as:

```
((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"]).Color = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF);
```

and

```
(Resources["PhoneAccentColor"]) = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF);
```

This really redefines accents, but nothing has impact on brackets. They are still green ...

Comment: If you can't find it in the docs, or tearing through templates, you might just have to go dig through the default brush resources and find the one that is that color of green and override it. Wish I knew the answer off the top of my head or had time to go dig around and figure it out.

Comment: I would attempt to find out where the style for those brackets come from using tools like [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/),  [Wpf Inspector](http://www.wpftutorial.net/Inspector.html) or [Mole](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/mole-for-visual-studio/).  I unfortunately don't know if any of those will be able to hook into universal apps but it's worth a try. (I can't try as on Windows 7 so can't build universal apps :( ).

Comment: My only other thought is that the brackets may be image resources rather than colors.

Comment: Sadly, neither of tools can inspect universal apps. About your suggestion on image resource - don't think so, cause it changes according to phone accent(set in OS settings).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a new resource to your application.  Then you simply would reference that.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppAccentBrush" Color="#012345"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then you would reference such in your page:

```
<TextBlock Text="Custom Accent" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"
           Foreground="{StaticResource AppAccentBrush}"/>
```

You can check this out [also](http://www.rudyhuyn.com/blog/2013/01/18/forcer-un-theme-sous-windows-phone-8/).  Though it is French it has quite a bit of useful content on this goal.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't help. This just adds a static resource in addition to theme resource with the same name and has no impact on brackets color.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the caretbrush property for the textboxes:

An XAML attribute example is as follows:

```
<TextBox CaretBrush="colorString"/>
```

For further usage, check out the documentation below.

Reference: [Textbox Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.windows.controls.textbox.caretbrush(v=vs.105).aspx)

**EDIT:**

As you mentioned, the textbox you are using is different one I checked that the universal app no longer uses the property CaretBrush:
[Windows Phone 8.1 (Silverlight) vs Windows Phone 8.1](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/Media/DiffLists/Windows%20Phone%208.1%20(Silverlight)-vs-Windows%20Phone%208.1.html)

Take a look at this note:

> Note: a removed type or member does not necessarily mean that it is no longer available. A removed type may indicate that the type has been moved to another namespace or assembly that has not been taken into account. A removed member may still be available on a base class.

The CaretBrush property is available in System.Windows.Controls namespace.

Comment: Wrong TextBox. In my case it is Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox.

Comment: Cause System.Windows.Controls not a case for Universal app development.

Comment: Ok. But yeah, CaretBrush property can no longer be changed for Universal apps.